# Generación de N-1 nº naturales aleatorios (¡'0' incluido!) cuya suma vale N

Tags: matemáticas, matlab, matrices, random

He probado el código que podéis encontrar a continuación, pero tarda demasiado tiempo en ejecutar: necesito algo casi instantáneo a poder ser posible.

```
clear all
N=1999;
a=0; b=2000;
while 1
r =round( a + (b-a).*rand(1,N));
suma=sum(r);
if sum(r)==2000
    display(r)
    display(suma)
    break;
end
end
```

¿Alguna forma de hacer algo lo más eficiente posible? Dado que necesitaré que funcione para vectores suficientemente grandes como el de este ejemplo.

Comment: No entiendo lo que quieres... segun tu titulo, vas a tener todo `1`'s y un `2`. Si `n=5` vas a tener 4 numeros de los cuales tres seran `1` y uno serà `2` (`1+1+1+2 = 5`).

Comment: ¡Gracias por responder @lois6b! Esa podría ser una solución, aunque podría haber otras -¡Se admiten ceros!

Comment: Ahhh cero ... pero 0 es un numero natural ? XD

Comment: ¡Jajajajaja, touché! Voy a cambiar el título de la pregunta para añadirlo, ¡gracias por la observación!

Comment: A ver si [esto](https://es.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/108083-how-to-create-a-random-row-vector-whose-sum-of-elements-and-number-of-elements-is-at-my-desire#answer_116819) te sirve. ^^

Comment: **Muchísimas gracias @lois6b!** Justo lo que necesitaba :-)